# Joule experiment in the low temperature regime

Tags: thermodynamics, low-temperature-physics

It is said that to prove mechanical energy can convert to heat energy, Joule measured the temperature increase of water after a free fall. He did his experiment at some waterfall. Because of the high value of the water heat capacity, the effect is not significant.

Now, could we repeat the experiment at the **low temperature regime**? It is well known that the heat capacity of matters decreases rapidly as $T\rightarrow 0 $. For example, for solids, it might go by the Debye $T^3$ law. Therefore, it seems possible that by a free fall of $1$ meter, the temperature of the matter changes significantly.

Is this idea feasible?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, where did you get the idea that Joule did his experiments at some waterfall? It should not matter, and Joule's result is statistically significant, or else there would be nobody taking him seriously. He left behind so much information about how he did his experiments, that [we can still reproduce them today, just by reading the papers he wrote.](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2014.0348)

Yes, your idea that, by doing the same experiments in the low temperature regime, it will be possible to get bigger changes in temperature, and thereby be  easier to take data.

However, to get low temperatures, you must always be running a refridgerator. It is about pumping out the heat that is always naturally leaking towards your system, and when this is far greater rate than the Joule style conversion of work to heat, then you can never hope to be able to get a better result.

And the whole discussion is moot anyway, because modern experiments to relate work to heat would be of far greater precision. We do not stick to early experiments when better ones appear.